# Copying from one text box to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have to copy the text from one text box to another using checkbox through jQuery I have applied jQuery event in my code, it works partially correct. Code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" value=""/>
        <input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate" value=""/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checker" id="checker" />
    </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#startdate").change(function(o){
        if($("#checker").is(":checked")){
            $("#enddate").val($("#startdate").val());
        }
      
});
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works as follows;
I always have checkbox checked by default hence whenever I insert the start date and then tab, the start date gets copied to enddate.

> **My Problem**

but now if uncheck the checkbox and change the start date and then recheck the check box, the start date is not copied, Now what should be done in this situation? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startdate").change(function(o){
        if($("#checker").is(":checked")){
            $("#enddate").val($("#startdate").val());
        }
    });

    $("#checker").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#enddate").val($("#startdate").val());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event for the `checkbox` as well:

```
$('#checker').bind('click', function () {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) { 
       $("#enddate").val($("#startdate").val());
    };
});
```

Or maybe **only** if `enddate` does not have a value:

```
$('#checker').bind('change', function () {
    var endDate = $('#enddate');

    if ($(this).attr('checked') && jQuery.trim(endDate.val()) === "") { 
       endDate.val($("#startdate").val());
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just `.bind()` a click event to your checkbox.

```
$('#checker').click(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $("#enddate").val($("#startdate").val());
   }
});
```